# How to check numeric datatype of edited cells with shiny / datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a datatable (DT) with a column of a numeric data type. Users can edit cells of this column, but I want to check if their input is a valid number.

The problem I have encountered: `input$myDT_cell_edit` returns, in any case, a string, e.g., "25.15" If I convert it with `as.numeric()` to a number, I get a warning whenever the input is not a valid number, e.g., "25m15". (Maybe I should just suppress this warning?)

I have tried three different solutions, but all of them are pretty complicated. I wonder if there is not a much simpler solution, something more native to DT, as checking for the correct input type is a standard-issue. Maybe I could use [column rendering](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html), but I am lacking the necessary JavaScript knowledge.

I have already solved the problem. But as I am new to R programming, Shiny, and DT, I would like to learn if I am something missing.

What follows is a minimal example (REPREX) to show what I have tried.

````
``` r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
library(tibble)

df <- tibble::as_tibble(c(20:25))

ui <- fluidPage(
        fluidRow(column(1,DT::DTOutput("myDT")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactiveValues(df = df)

    showData <- reactive({
        DT::datatable(
            data$df,
            options = list(
                dom = 't',
                autoWidth = TRUE,
                columnDefs = list(
                    list(width = '75px', targets = c(0,1)),
                    list(type = 'natural', targets = 0)
                )
            ),
            colnames = c('ID' = 1),
            plugins = 'natural',
            editable = list(
                target = "cell", disable = list(columns = 0))
        )

    })

    output$myDT <- DT::renderDT({showData()})

    #####

    ########################################### first version
    # checkValue <-  function(info) {
    #     k = NULL
    #     i = info$row
    #     j = info$col
    #     k =  tryCatch({
    #         as.numeric(info$value)
    #         }, warning = function(war) {
    #             k <<- as.numeric(data$df[i,j][[1]])
    #         }, finally = {
    #             k = as.numeric(k)
    #         })
    #     data$df[i,j][[1]] = k
    #     data$df
    # }

    ########################################## second version
    # checkValue <- function(info) {
    #     v = "[\\!#$%&()*/:;<=>?@_`|~{}ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ]"
    #     i = info$row
    #     j = info$col
    #     k = info$value
    #     if (regexec(v, k) == -1) {
    #         data$df[i,j][[1]] = as.numeric(k)
    #     }
    #     data$df
    # }

    ########################################## third version
    checkValue <- function(info) {
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        oldValue  <-  data$df[i,j][[1]]
        newValue = suppressWarnings(isolate(DT::coerceValue(info$value, as.double(oldValue))))
        if (!is.na(newValue)) {data$df[i,j][[1]] <- newValue}
        data$df
    }

    observeEvent(input$myDT_cell_edit, {
        showData <- DT::replaceData(
            DT::dataTableProxy("myDT"),
            checkValue(input$myDT_cell_edit),
            resetPaging = FALSE
        )
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4640
```

![](https://i.imgur.com/OKAwOKL.png)

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
````

Comment: You can restrict the editing to accept only numbers if you use my fork of `DT`. To install it: `remotes::install_github("stla/DT", ref = "numericedit")`. To request the numeric editing for some columns, set the option `editable = list(target = "cell", numeric = INDICES)`, where `INDICES` is the vector of the indices of the columns for which you want the numeric editing. I have proposed this feature to the authors of `DT`, but it seems they are on holliday.

Comment: Thanks! I will change my program in the next few days accordingly.